# Wait for a file to be created before writing to it

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
if (!File.Exists(fileName))
{
    File.Create(fileName);
}
File.WriteAllText(fileName, contents);
```

However, every time I run it I get an IOException:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Frankie\Commander\config\freq.txt' because it is being used by another process.

How do I make the File.WriteAllText() wait until it's done being created?

Comment: This could be an issue with another instance of your program never dropping the file handle. Try restarting your ide and trying again.

Comment: I've tried restarting Visual Studio and my computer. It also does it when I just run the exe with no IDE attached.

Comment: if these answers still aren't working for you try copying the file to a different one and deleting the old file and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx) method creates the file for you, so this is all you need:

```
if (!File.Exists(fileName))
{
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, contents);
}
```

If you don't care about potentially overwriting the file, you could even omit the `File.Exists` check, as `WriteAllText` will overwrite an existing file.

The reason you're having a problem with your original code is that `File.Create` opens a `FileStream` for the file, and so locks it; you'd have to close it first before you could write to it.

Comment: If I were to manually close the FileStream, would it let me write to it with no issues?

Answer (score 0):

Close the file after creating it:

```
if (!File.Exists(fileName))
{
    File.Create(fileName).Close();
}
File.WriteAllText(fileName, contents);
```